# Firebase Pagination - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been fighting this one for hours and can't seem to figure out 2 things.

1. How can I show all of the latest posts first (adding those to my array of "items". I'm using "queryEndingAtValue" with "queryLimitedToLast" and now my posts aren't showing at all.
2. My when it was working it was adding the items to my array several times.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my db 
[image: snapshot sample of my db]

Here's my code, very new to firebase and really will just admit I don't know what I'm doing here..

```
 func downloadPostsFromFirebase(withValue: String) {
        // 1 - Get a reference to the database
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "items-for-sale")

        var startKey = withValue

        var count = GlobalConstants.FirebaseConstants.numerOfPostsPerPage

        var query = ref.queryOrderedByKey()

        if startKey != nil {
            query = query.queryEnding(atValue: startKey)
            count += 1
        }

        query.queryLimited(toLast: UInt(count)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard var children = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] else {
                // Handle error
                return
            }

            if startKey != nil && !children.isEmpty {
                // TODO - If the number of items in the array is equal to the number of items in the db now, then stop?
                for child in snapshot.children {

                    // instance of ItemForSale, it's added to the array that contains the latest version of the data.
                    let itemForSaleSingle = ItemForSale(snapshot: child as! FIRDataSnapshot)

                    startKey = itemForSaleSingle.key

                    self.items.append(itemForSaleSingle)
                    print("Total items count is \(self.items.count)")
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                    print("start key is \(startKey)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I answered #2 below. Please limit yourself to a single question per post. I recommend searching a bit for the pagination, as I'm quite certain I've answered questions about that multiple times in the past few weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My when it was working it was adding the items to my array several times.

You're listening for a `value` event. This event fires whenever there is a change in the data of the query. And whenever it fires, it includes the full data for the query.

That means if you start with three items in the list, you get these three items:

```
1
2
3
```

Then if you add a fourth item, you get a value event with:

```
1
2
3
4
```

You'll note that there's overlap between the initial collection and the one you get after adding a value, which is the reason you see duplicate messages.

The simplest way to handle this is to listen for `child_added` events, instead of value events. In the scenario above, you'd initially get three `child_added` events:

```
1
2
3
```

And then when adding an item, you'd get a single additional `child_added`:

```
4
```

Using `child_added` also simplifies your code, since you don't need to handle the collection anymore:

```
query.queryLimited(toLast: UInt(count)).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    // instance of ItemForSale, it's added to the array that contains the latest version of the data.
    let itemForSaleSingle = ItemForSale(snapshot: snapshot as! FIRDataSnapshot)
```

Comment: To add a quick note: if you need to read in a group of data at one time via the .value event, to avoid duplicating data the array would need to be initialized each time so it could be re-loaded with data; self.items = [] inside the closure and before iterating over the snapshot.children will do that. But as @frankvanpuffelen states, the .childAdded event is usually the best solution.